New column added to DB table truncates it after deployment with DACPAC
Azure DacPac Task truncates my table after just adding a new column in vs sql project Table designer where the script is a create table... I think that I'm not doing the correct way to add new column to table and deploying by dacpac without the risk of data losses.
Any advice?
Kind regards
Dacpac deployment by azure devops works but after deployment a new column to existing table it truncates table after deployment
Some related questions:

[1] : DACPAC package with complex changes

